# Cycle2 Swipe gesture does not work on any mobile device

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, cycle2

I'm using Cycle2 on my site and want to add support for swipe functionality on mobile devices.

I'm not using jQuery mobile, so I've added the [Cycle2 support plugin](http://malsup.github.io/min/jquery.cycle2.swipe.min.js) for Swipe. I've added this to a file called [site.js](http://hancockproperties.francesca-designed.me/wp-content/themes/codrington-road/js/site.js) which is loaded in straight after jQuery so it should be available.

I've added the following to my page to make the swipe gesture work:

```
echo '<div class="cycle-slideshow"
   data-cycle-pause-on-hover="true"
   data-cycle-swipe="true"
   data-cycle-swipe-fx="scrollHorz"
   data-cycle-pager=".cycle-pager">';
```

But I'm not getting any response on mobile. Nor am I getting any error messages. I've checked that it isn't caching the files, and that the plugin is there in `site.js` but I'm just not getting anything. It does nothing. No swiping, just the standard fade.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using Jquery mobile also, so you can try this code, but it's responds but not so fluid

Add this plugin:

/* Swipe Plugin for Cycle2; Copyright (c) 2012 M. Alsup; v20141007 */
          !function(a){"use strict";a.event.special.swipe=a.event.special.swipe||{scrollSupressionThreshold:10,durationThreshold:1e3,horizontalDistanceThreshold:30,verticalDistanceThreshold:75,setup:function(){var b=a(this);b.bind("touchstart",function(c){function d(b){if(g){var c=b.originalEvent.touches?b.originalEvent.touches[0]:b;e={time:(new Date).getTime(),coords:[c.pageX,c.pageY]},Math.abs(g.coords[0]-e.coords[0])>a.event.special.swipe.scrollSupressionThreshold&&b.preventDefault()}}var e,f=c.originalEvent.touches?c.originalEvent.touches[0]:c,g={time:(new Date).getTime(),coords:[f.pageX,f.pageY],origin:a(c.target)};b.bind("touchmove",d).one("touchend",function(){b.unbind("touchmove",d),g&&e&&e.time-g.timea.event.special.swipe.horizontalDistanceThreshold&&Math.abs(g.coords[1]-e.coords[1])e.coords[0]?"swipeleft":"swiperight"),g=e=void 0})})}},a.event.special.swipeleft=a.event.special.swipeleft||{setup:function(){a(this).bind("swipe",a.noop)}},a.event.special.swiperight=a.event.special.swiperight||a.event.special.swipeleft}(jQuery);

And then this code in your js files:

```
      $('#my-div div.slides').after('<nav id="pagination"></nav>');

      $('#my-div div.slides').cycle(
      {
        fx: "scrollHorz",
        slides: ".slide1",
        timeout: 0,
        speed: 200,
        pager: "#pagination",
        pagerTemplate: "<a href='#'>{{slideNum}}</a>",
        pagerActiveClass: "active",
        **swipe: true**
      });
```